# Server Error loading HttpModule

Tags: web-config, httpmodule, iis-express

I am stumped and need some suggestions in resolving the following error 
I am getting in my application that is configured to use
an HttpModule that I have created:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'. 

...

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load
type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'.

...

Stack Trace: 

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'.]

...

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'.]

...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

The web server is IIS Express 7.0.

In the web.config file, the code for the  element is:

```
   <system.webServer>
       <modules>
           <add name="ResponseModifier"
                type="namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer" />
       </modules>
   </system.webServer>

The assembly for the HttpModule resides in 
C:\...\HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS\Bin\ResponseModifier.dll
```

I have also tried placing the source for the HttpModule in the App_Code directory
but I am still getting Server Error on loading the HttpModule.

In this 2nd scenario, I am getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer' from assembly 'App_Code'. 

...

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load
type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer' from assembly 'App_Code'.

...

Stack Trace: 

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer' from
assembly 'App_Code'.]

...

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'
from assembly 'App_Code'.]

...

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer'
from assembly 'App_Code'.]

...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

I have also tried using the Visual Studio Development Web Server instead of the IIS Express Web Server.
I tried this server with both scenarios:
 - with the assembly in the bin folder
 - with the source in the App_Code folder.

These scenarios respectively produced the following Errors:

```
Server Error in '/HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 

...

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ResponseModifer'.
(C:\...\HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS\web.config line 8)

...

Source File: C:\...\HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS\web.config    Line: 8 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272


Server Error in '/HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 

...

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ResponseModifer' from assembly 'App_Code'.  
(C:\...\HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS\web.config line 8)

...

Source File: C:\...\HttpModulePreSendRequestContentCS\web.config    Line: 8 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Any suggestions as to what I can do to resolve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I believe your module add is incorrect.

```
<add name="NameOfModule" type="Namespace.NameOfModule, AssemblyName" />
```

Is the typical way I see it, so not knowing your namespace for this module, it'd look closer to:

```
<add name="ResponseModifier" type="ActualNameSpaceGoesHere.namespaceResponseModifier.ResponseModifer, ResponseModifier" />
```